# Who's The Queen's favourite child?

Tags: the-crown

In The Crown's "Favourites" (S04E04) Prince Philip tells The Queen that she has an obvious favourite child, and she sets on a quest to figure it out.

She has lunch with each of their children, and she seems to be disappointed with each one of them for various reasons. I was hoping they at least hint at a solution, my guess while watching was that at the end Philip will reveal it's the horses (she is portrayed as an avid horse breeder), or that he will tell her it's the state (she mentions that she is a mother to Britain).

Clearly, the show is trying to not step on any unnecessary toes here. But maybe I missed something? Was there anything subtle, or was it a deliberate choice, leaving the audience to interpret, as did I?

Answer (score 3):

The answer is revealed in the the dialogue between Elizabeth and Philip at the end of the episode.

> Elizabeth: And as for Andrew...
>  Philip: Your favourite?

Philip is the one who introduced the idea that Elizabeth had a favorite child, and that it was obvious which child it was. Elizabeth was skeptical of the idea, but felt compelled to explore the matter and figure it out for herself. While she never explicitly acknowledged that Philip was correct, she also did not seem surprised, nor did she put up any argument, when Philip finally revealed who he was referring to.

Philip was able to recognize something about Elizabeth that she could not see in herself. To the extent that there *is* an answer, the answer is who Philip says it is.

Comment: I didn't miss that. Philip was asking if Andrew is her favourite. She gave him a look that said "no".

Comment: @Inkblot Regardless, it was Philip who told the queen earlier on that She had a favourite - and this was Philip expressing his belief the Andrew was that favourite and wondering if She had realised it yet.   Andrew is the answer that the episode provides.

Comment: @racraman: But he didn't *say* "your favourite". He asked "your favourite?", meaning "so you think that Andrew is your favourite?", that's not *an answer*.

Comment: He's NOT asking, he's clearly stating that Andrew IS her favorite! Unfortunately, perhaps the inflection is not something you reallised.

Comment: He is asking a question...but it's not if Andrew is her favorite, he asking if Andrew has as many issues as her other children.

Comment: I’ve expanded my answer to reflect the points brought up here. Feel free to disagree, but I don’t see any reason to doubt the answer as it was given in the episode.